# If $x \mapsto \|x\|^2$, where $n \geqslant2.$ Find the partial derivatives, gradient and the derivative at the point $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and $x \mapsto \|x\|^2$, where $n \geqslant2.$ Find the partial derivatives, gradient and the derivative at the point $x$.

So for the partials I seem to get $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} = 2x_1, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} = 2x_2, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} = 2x_n$. This would imply that the gradient is $\nabla f = (2x_1, \dots, 2x_n)$ and at point $x$ It would be $\nabla f(x) = 2x$? By the derivative I assume they mean the Jacobian? Wouldn't the Jacobian for $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be just the transpose of the gradient i.e $J = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 2x_1 \\ 2x_2 \\ \vdots \\ 2x_n \end{pmatrix} ?$

Comment: Two comments. First, your last index should be $n$, not $i$. Second, the gradient is actually a *vector* (hence a *column vector*) and the Jacobian is a linear map $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, hence represented by a *row* vector. I don't know if you're supposed to justify the differentiability of $f$ by noting that the partial derivatives are continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the notes! Edited the index. I've denoted the gradient as a vector, however the problem statement asked to find the gradient at point $x$, which seemed a bit odd?

Comment: No, why is that odd? But I still insist that your $x$ vector should be written as a column, not as a row. It's super important to get this right when doing multivariable calculus/analysis.

Comment: As a column do you mean that I should write $\nabla f = \begin{pmatrix} 2x_1 \\ 2x_2 \\ \vdots \\ 2x_n \end{pmatrix}?$

Comment: Yes. And $Df(x)$, the Jacobian, is the transpose, i.e., a $1\times n$ matrix.